# Which Content Type ID i should use inside my CSOM code to change the list item content type. the content ID at site level or at list level

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, csom, content-type

I have the following CSOM code to change the content type of a list item:

```
var salesCT = context.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById("0x01030024AB2893A99597438351BDC84B0E90F0020062E098DB68903646A202CAC6AD5F1A1E");
context.Load(salesCT);
context.ExecuteQuery();
List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Order Management");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

context.Load(collListItem,
items => items.Include(
item=>item.ContentType,
item=>item["ContentTypeId"],
item=>item["OrderReferenceNumber"],
item => item.Id));


context.Load(collListItem);
ontext.Load(context.Site);
context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem item in collListItem)
                {

                 if (item["OrderReferenceNumber"].ToString().Contains("QO") && item.Id == 1001)
                        item["ContentTypeId"] = salesCT.Id;

                }




                    }
```

But I am a bit confused, as the content type has 2 IDs, one at the list level with `0x01030024AB2893A99597438351BDC84B0E90F002` and one at the site level which is `x01030024AB2893A99597438351BDC84B0E90F0020062E098DB68903646A202CAC6AD5F1A1E`.

So which Content type ID I should use inside the `context.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById(***)`?

Answer (score 0):

According to below answer on Stack Overflow, you need to use **List Content Type ID**. Try using it if it works for you.

[How to change the content type of list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908983/how-to-change-the-content-type-of-list-items)

[image]

Comment: Hi SharePoint TestDev, Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help other users to find the correct answer easily.